# I need help creating a table from a CSV file

Tags: r

I created a script in R.

```
table_1 <- transactions %>% group_by(prod_cat) %>% 
       summarise("Total Sales" = sum(amount), 
       "Sales Per AMount Transaction" = count(customer_id)
```

but I get the following error.

> error in usemethod("groups") no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class"factor"

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mcve], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. You tagged [tag:python] but your code is in R? Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Done, tag removed.

Comment: Also, please include any packages you are using in the body of your question. `%>%` is not a base R operator.

Answer (score 0):

to get better help you should post a [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/).

Working with aggregation in R has plently of documentation, example [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html).

As an example you can find below a sample code that uses the `iris` dataset from the `ISLR` package. The code shows a portion of the dataset, its structure and an example of use of the group by and summarise functions.

```
library(ISLR)
library(tidyverse)

head(iris)
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
str(iris)

'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise("Total Sepal Length" = sum(Sepal.Length))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    `Total Sepal Length`
  <fct>                     <dbl>
1 setosa                     250.
2 versicolor                 297.
3 virginica                  329.
```